# Editing Checkboxes, radios, and dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql, html

I found this site providing code for creating, reading, updating and deleting. I am confused about how to add checkboxes, radio buttons, and dropdowns

http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/

I'm not concerned with the pagination at all——my primary concern is to be able to put in two dropdowns, yes/no radio button, and a collection of 3 checkboxes using PHP.

My attempts were useless as when I tried to edit choices the values did not stay. Included are my three files: pets, editpets, and view.(I changed the file name for database, etc.)

```
 <?php
     function renderForm($first, $last, $pets, $size, $type, $years, $error)
     {
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>New Customer</title>
     </head>
     <body>

     <?php
     // display possible errors
     if ($error != '')
     {
     echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
     }
     ?>

     <form action="" method="post">
     <div>
     <strong>First Name:</strong> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo  
     $first; ?>" /> 
     <strong>Last Name:</strong> <input align="center" type="text" name="lastname" value="<
    ?php echo $last; ?>" /><br/>

     <p><strong>No. Pets </strong>
     <select name="pets">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option> 
      <option value="4">4</option> 
     </select>
     </p>
     <br/>


     <strong>Size? </strong>
     <br/>
      Big<input type="radio" value="Yes"  name="size" checked><?php echo $size; ?><br />
      Small<input type="radio" value="No" name="size"<?php echo $size; ?><br />
      <br />


<p><strong>Type</strong><br/>
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Cats
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Dogs
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Others
</p>
<br/>
 <strong>Years? </strong>
 <select name="year">
  <option value="Five or Less">Five or More</option>
  <option value="Six or More">Six or More</option>
 </select><br/>

 <input style="color:purple;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create My Order :-)">
 </div>
 </form>

 <center><a href="view.php">Click Here for Orders</a></center>
 </body>
 </html>

 <?php
 }




 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if my form submits and, upon triumph, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 // get form data, check its validity
 $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
 $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']));
 $pets = $_POST['pets'];
 $size = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['size']));
 $type = serialize(mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['type'])));
 $years = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['years']));

 // check to make sure everything is filled!
 if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $pets == '' || $size == '' || $type == '' || $years == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, show the form again
 renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $pets, $size, $type, $years, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT customers SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', pets='$pets', size='$size', type='$type', years='$years'")
 or die(mysql_error());

 // once saved, redirect to cheview page
 header("Location: view.php");
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form is not submitted, show my form again.
 {
 renderForm('','','','','','','');
 }
?>


    <?php

$types = array("Cats", "Dogs", "Others");

 function renderForm($id, $firstname, $lastname, $pets, $size, $type, $years, $error)
 {
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?>
 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <div>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
 <strong>First Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" /><br/>
 <strong>Last Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" /><br/>

 <p><strong>No. Pets </strong>
 <select name="pets">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option> 
  <option value="4">4</option> 
 </select>
 </p>

  <strong>Size? </strong>
 <br/>
  Big<input type="radio" value="Yes"  name="size" checked><?php echo $size; ?><br />
  Small<input type="radio" value="No" name="size"<?php echo $size; ?><br />
  <br />

  <br />
  <br />
<p><strong>Type</strong><br/>
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Cats
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Dogs
    <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type[]"/>
    Others
</p>

<br/>
 <strong>Years? </strong>
 <select name="year">
  <option value="Five or Less">Five or More</option>
  <option value="Six or More">Six or More</option>
 </select><br/>
<br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Resubmit My Order :-)">
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php
 }


 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 // check for id being an integer
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
 $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']));
 $pets = $_POST['pets'];
 $size = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['size']));
 $type = serialize(mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['type'])));
 $years = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['years']));



 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $pets == '' || $size == '' || $type == '' || $years == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($id, $firstname, $lastname, $pets, $size, $type, $years, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', pets='$pets', size='$size', type='$type', years='$years' WHERE id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error());

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php");
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='$id' ")
 or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $firstname = $row['firstname'];
 $lastname = $row['lastname'];
 $pets = $row['pets'];
 $size = $row['size'];
 $type = serialize($row['type']);
 $years = $row['years'];


 // show form
 renderForm($id, $firstname, $lastname, $pets, $size, $type, $years, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View customer orders</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

        include('connect-db.php');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers")
                or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> 
                   <th>First Name</th> 
                   <th>Last Name</th> 
                   <th>Pets</th> 
                   <th>Size</th>
                   <th>Type</th> 
                   <th>Years</th> 
                   <th></th> 
                   <th></th>
             </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {


                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['pets'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['size'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['type']. '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['years'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
        }


        echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="pets.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm honestly lost at this point. I've been working on this for an entire month and I have no idea what I'm doing any more. I'd be so thankful if anyone can help me to edit this to work.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Right, to get your saved results from the database I'm sure you're aware of how to do this.

For your radio buttons you're going to want to select your 'size' value from the database and use an if statement to determine which radio button will be 'checked'

forename/surname is a matter of simply getting the forename/surname from database and setting the appropriate `input` tags to the acquired values

You've already posted a technique for handling the combo/drop-down boxes

you'd perform a similar process for the 'type' checkboxes, compare your database values to the values of your checkbox `input` tags and if the value matches, set the checkbox to checked.

Next time please be more specific in what you are asking for help with and separate your code into segments that correspond with the files it is contained in.

if you have 3 files, have a code block for each file.

Comment: As for the purpose, it was a task I was assigned to do. I tried to remain as close as possible to the site I saw this on, to be organized.

Right now, I'm in SOS mode. Everything, technically works fine. My only, absolute issue is that I don't know what to add in order to see the values I selected, appear on the edit page. If I checked all three checkboxes, how can I see this on the edit(uodate) page? The same with radio and delete. Ive looked around, thoroughly and nothing I add seems to give me this capability.

Comment: Hi Timmy,

I used what you provided for me, but I was not able to retain the selected values for when I click submit form and attempt to edit. I removed the escape string and everything. Everything seemed to be fine when I removed them, otherwise.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm going to be chastised for sloppiness if I use what you've provided.

The provider of the code sent me a message that I thought I understood, but I cannot be sure of what to make of it now.

His message wrt dropdowns was:

Just because you'd be using inputs other than the standard text input doesn't mean that the way they would be stored in the database would be significantly different. Let's take a dropdown for example -- a select element:

Comment: <select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

If you needed to store this in the database, you would probably use a varchar, since you need a string with a limited number of characters. Say the user selected "Volvo". When the form submits, you would use PHP to get the value of the select ("volvo") using $_POST['car']. You would save that value in the database.

Comment: If you wanted to edit the value, you would start by getting the saved value from the database. Then, for each option, you would check if the value of the option matched the saved value using PHP.

<option value="volvo" <?php if ($saved_value == 'volvo') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>

If so, it would result in this:

<option value="volvo" selected="selected">